# How to display Power BI reports with filters in iframe in angular application

Tags: iframe, powerbi, angular7, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I am trying to display the PowerBi report with filters in Iframe in my angular application.
I successfully display below embedded URL in the iframe without filters.

```
<iframe src="https://msit.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=xxx&autoAuth=true&ctid=xx&config=xxx"></iframe>
```

here I need to filter the reports against some RequestId and then display it in the iframe.

filtered URL
https://msit.powerbi.com/groups/xxx/reports/xxx/ReportSectioncxxx?filter=RequestDetails/Number eq 'xxxx'

getting below error when I tried this in iframe:

***Refused to display 'URL' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.***

How to convert this filtered URL as embed URL to display in an iframe.

Comment: Append `&ctid=ctid` to the end of the query string so that it looks like `https://msit.powerbi.com/groups/xxx/reports/xxx/ReportSectioncxxx?filter=RequestDetails/Number eq 'xxxx''&ctid=ctid`. You can find the explanation here: [Filter a report using query string parameters in the URL - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters#reports-in-apps)

Comment: still the same error. is it needed to add "reportEmbed" in the URL?  base URL without filters works have that text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Embeded filter URL

https://msit.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=xxx&autoAuth=true&filter=RequestDetails/SRNumber eq 'xxx'&ctid=xxx